# Loop Through List And Keep Index Count VB.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I irate through a list/array in vb.net and also keep the count of the current item I'm on without having to declare an explicit counter variable?

The result that I am trying to achieve is as follows.

```
dim i as integer = 0 'evil counter variable
dim arr() as string = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
for each item in arr
    console.writeline("Item """ & item & """ is index " & i)           
    i+=1
next
```

Without having to declare "i" on its own line

---

Python has a shorthand way of doing this as follows.

```
arr=["a","b","c","d","e"]
for i, item in enumerate(arr):
    print("Item """ + item + """ is index " + str(i))
```

A similar implementation in vb.net would be ideal.

*edit*

The significant part of the code is the enumeration. Not the printing of the values.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks! LINQ looks promising. I don't know if it will work for every of the issue at hand. Definitely a handful of them, but I'd still like to have some sort of way to do what the python code does in vb.net.

Comment: Rather than a For Each loop, a For n loop seems like it would be more comparable to the python code - ie a "built in" indexer

Answer (score 0):

It's not as good as the Python way, but this will do as you require:

```
dim arr() as string = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
for i as integer = 0 to arr.length - 1
    console.writeline("Item """ & arr(i) & """ is index " & i)           
next
```

Again, not as clean but it does as you need :)

Comment: Yea I was just about to edit the question to include this implementation. It works but its still a mess to type out and then read. Thanks though!

Comment: You dont need a special `item` variable: you can use `arr(i)` in the output statement

Comment: @Philip556677 this answer removes the need for the extra variable, makes it cleaner for what you need :)

Comment: @Philip556677 using the string formatting method rather than concatenating with & and ticks and quotes is even cleaner still - more so even than the pythin version

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim arr() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
For i = 0 To arr.GetUpperBound(0)
    Debug.Print($"Item {arr(i)}  is index {i}")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) on a Linq `Select()`:

```
Console.Write(String.Join(vbCrLf, arr.Select(Function(s, i) "Item " & s & " is Index " & i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of possible solutions would not be complete without a Reflection hack, so let's go old school and use an enumerator

```
Dim arr() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
Dim enumer As IEnumerator = arr.GetEnumerator
Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo = enumer.GetType.GetField("_index", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
While enumer.MoveNext
    Dim item As String = DirectCast(enumer.Current, String)
    Console.WriteLine($"item: {item} is at index: {fi.GetValue(enumer)}")
End While
```

A little explanation is needed.  `arr.GetEnumerator` returns a [SZArrayEnumerator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1b80aad630219ba5).  This enumerator uses the private field `_index` to keep track of the array index of the item returned by the Enumerator.    The code uses reflection to access the value of `_index`.

Since this is not a generic Enumerator, the type returned by the `Current` property is `System.Object` and needs to be cast back to a `String`.